# when running easy_install PIL, I got the error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, easy-install

My system environment is :
   MAC: OS X YOSEMITE 10.10.1
 XCODE: Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
Python: 2.7.6

when I run "sudo easy_install PIL",I got a error：

```
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

have any solution for this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the command line tools for xcode.  Type `xcode-select --install` from a terminal prompt.

Comment: Amazing! I had try many methods to solve it,bug both do not work for me! Your way works for me!Thanks a lot!